# Wordpress first post in different container

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, posts

I'm new in Wordpress and I have a problem with posts loop. I need first post in different container then the rest. 
I want do template like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
          first post
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
                posts
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did something like this but it's not working well:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : $postCounter = 0 ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : $postCounter++ ?>
            <?php foreach (array(the_post()) as $post): ?>
                <?php if ($postCounter == 1): ?>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h1>Tu będzie pierwszy post</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <?php if ($postCounter > 1): ?>
                                <h1>Tu będzie kolejny post</h1>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean `$first` to `true`, and then change it to `false` at the first post. Then all you need to do is to add different HTML depending on if `$first` is `true` or not.

```php
    <?php 
    if ( have_posts() ) : 

        $first = true;

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if ( $first ):
                $first = false;
                ?>
                <div>First Post</div>
                <?php
            else:
               ?>
               <div>Not First Post</div>
               <?php
            endif;

        endwhile; 
    endif; 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but I'll use bootstrap. I want have first post in container-fluid but rest of posts want ot have in container and I have problem because if I use your code will have own container and row.

Efect will be like below

```
    if ( have_posts() ) : 

        $first = true;

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            if ( $first ):
                $first = false;
                ?>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                      <div class="row">
                            first post
                      </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            else:
               ?>
               <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                            post 2
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                            post 3
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                            post 4
                      </div>
                </div>
               <?php
            endif;

        endwhile; 
    endif; 
    ?>
```